# How to rename a seam project

Tags: jboss, project, seam, rename

I created a seam project using seam-gen utility tool. I want to change the name of the project. How can I update it ?

your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of the project do you want to change? The title of the pages, the name of the folder, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your project is in an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans), you can refactor it and rename it.  If you haven't put too much work into it you can run seam-gen again with a different project name.

Comment: i ended up generating a new project with the required name.  Because seam-gen generates so many configuration files which reflects project name.